# NativeScript videorecorder, How to add description tag?

Tags: nativescript

How I can add a description tag to the video file captured with [nativescript-videorecorder](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-videorecorder/) plugin?
Or probably better to use another plugin?

I'm expecting to get a video file stored on the phone with a description tag, which will be parsed on the desktop with another tool